# Software Architecture and xtemplate

Tags: best-practices, latex3, package-writing, xtemplate

When writing a package, there may be the situation that several things need to interact to make a complete product. When using `xtemplate`, I can define each part as an object. This means that the templates I define will need some organized way to interact with each other. That also means that templates for those objects can’t be mixed-and-matched.

What is the best way to organize parts that are made using `xtemplate`? My first thought would be to define objects and templates for the parts, then to define an object that represents the whole product, and finally to define a template that requires the specific parts as instances, with the template code putting everything together.